# Django, nested requests through microservices in a live server test environment

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I found out, after a few checks, that in a live server test environment of Django, fired up as follows

```
python manage.py test <SERVICE> --liveserver=localhost:8888 --keepdb
```

nested REST requests through a set of microservices are served up to a depth level of 2 requests. In other words, if the API test case makes a request to Service 1, which makes a request to Service 2, everything is ok.
In the case where the Service 2 makes another request to a Service 3, then this request hangs on infinitely.

Is there something to be set for handling nested requests in a live server test environment?

Everything is fine using the development server of Django, which handles these requests without issues.